# Sum children values and save result to parent in n-ary tree in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree

I have a tree in Javascript with the following structure, a simple example:

```
tree: [
    {
      id: 'A'
      parents: []
      children: ['B']
      value: 1
    },
    {
      id: 'B'
      parents: ['A']
      children: ['C', 'D']
      value: 1
    },
    {
      id: 'C'
      parents: ['B']
      children: []
      value: 1
    },
    {
      id: 'D'
      parents: ['B']
      children: []
      value: 1
    }
]

      A
      |
      B
     / \
    C   D
```

Every node can have an unfixed number of children, and I'm using the parents array to know the tree root (when the parents array is empty).

What I'm trying to do is a recursion function: the sum of the child values is saved in the parent (overwriting the value). If there is only one child, the child value is saved in the parent. So the values accumulate to the root.

Is the tree structure fine? How can I do the function?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Expected result:

```
tree: [
        {
          id: 'A'
          parents: []
          children: ['B']
          value: 2
        },
        {
          id: 'B'
          parents: ['A']
          children: ['C', 'D']
          value: 2
        },
        {
          id: 'C'
          parents: ['B']
          children: []
          value: 1
        },
        {
          id: 'D'
          parents: ['B']
          children: []
          value: 1
        }
    ]
```

Another example:

```
       A
     /   \
    B     E
   / \    |
  C   D   F
```

All node values = 1.

Expected result:

```
tree: [
        {
          id: 'A'
          parents: []
          children: ['B','E']
          value: 3
        },
        {
          id: 'B'
          parents: ['A']
          children: ['C', 'D']
          value: 2
        },
        {
          id: 'C'
          parents: ['B']
          children: []
          value: 1
        },
        {
          id: 'D'
          parents: ['B']
          children: []
          value: 1
        },
        {
          id: 'E'
          parents: ['A']
          children: ['F']
          value: 1
        },
        {
          id: 'F'
          parents: ['E']
          children: []
          value: 1
        }
    ]
```

A value = B value + E value.

B value = C value + D value.

E value = F value.

Comment: Why do you store your nodes in an array? Why not store it as a real tree? At least make them addressable by id.

Comment: The data of the tree comes from a graph made by a user, so this structure is built from these data. It can be changed into a real tree, this is what I got first.

Comment: Yes, for your function to work out you will need some kind of tree structure, so you might as well convert the data explicitly

Comment: is the data sorted, like root comes first? do you need a tree structure, not a flat array, or do you want the flat array?

Comment: The data is not sorted, to know the root I check if the node has parents or not. The flat array is not necessary, the structure can be other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the reference of the root elemnts as well as every item in a hash table for faster access. Then iterate the root elements for getting the wanted sum by using recursion for the children.

This approach just updates the given array.

```js
function update(array) {
    var root = [],
        references = array.reduce((r, o) => {
            if (!o.parents.length) {
                root.push(o.id);
            }
            r[o.id] = o;
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null));
    
    root.reduce(function sum(s, id) {
        var o = references[id];
        return s + (o.value = o.children.reduce(sum, 0) || o.value);
    }, 0);

    return array;
}


var data1 = [{ id: 'A', parents: [], children: ['B'], value: 1 }, { id: 'B', parents: ['A'], children: ['C', 'D'], value: 1 }, { id: 'C', parents: ['B'], children: [], value: 1 }, { id: 'D', parents: ['B'], children: [], value: 1 }],
    data2 = [{ id: 'A', parents: [], children: ['B', 'E'], value: 1 }, { id: 'B', parents: ['A'], children: ['C', 'D'], value: 1 }, { id: 'C', parents: ['B'], children: [], value: 1 }, { id: 'D', parents: ['B'], children: [], value: 1 }, { id: 'E', parents: ['A'], children: ['F'], value: 1 }, { id: 'F', parents: ['E'], children: [], value: 1 }]

console.log(update(data1));
console.log(update(data2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The function is nice, but the sum is only for the accumulate value. If a accumulate value goes up to a parent, we don't care about the original value of the parent, so we don't use it to sum.

Comment: i don't understand please add the wanted result to the question.

Comment: Done. A value is 2, because B value is the sum of C and D values. The original B value is not used.

Comment: do you want only to get the sum of the leaves?

Comment: The sum of the leaves, saving each result in the parent. I added another example.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: And if value has more than one value, for instance: `value: {A: 1, B: 2}` How would you do it in this code?

Comment: @KonaKona, then you need to inspect the value object and get all properties for summing. i suggest to try yourself and if it does not work, ask a new question. in comments answering an extended/different question is not the right place.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that the tree structure is not the same as yours, but you can insert other properties too (*id* for example) if you want.

```
const tree = {
    value: 1,
    children: [{
        value: 1,
        children: [{
            value: 1,
            children: null
        },
        {
            value: 1,
            children: null
        }]
    }]
};

function sum(node) {
    var childSum = 0;
    if (!node.children) return node.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        childSum += sum(node.children[i]);
    }
    node.value = childSum;
    return childSum;
}

sum(tree);
```

Comment: The function is exactly what I need, but the structure is hard to obtain because the data from which I get the nodes is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let tree = [
  {
    id: 'A',
    parents: [],
    children: ['B'],
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'B',
    parents: ['A'],
    children: ['C', 'D'],
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'C',
    parents: ['B'],
    children: [],
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'D',
    parents: ['B'],
    children: [],
    value: 1
  }
];
let leafNodes = [];
function ArrayToObject(array, keyField) {
  return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item[keyField]] = item;
    if (!item.children.length && !leafNodes.includes(item[keyField])) leafNodes.push(item[keyField]);
    return obj;
  }, {});
}


let treeObject = ArrayToObject(tree, 'id');

addSumToParentNode(leafNodes);

function addSumToParentNode(childNodes) {
  if (childNodes.length) {
    let parentNodes = [];
    childNodes.map(child => {
      if (treeObject[child].parents.length) {
        let parent = treeObject[child].parents[0];
        if (!parentNodes.includes(parent)) parentNodes.push(parent);
        treeObject[parent].value += treeObject[child].value;
      }
    });
    addSumToParentNode(parentNodes);
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(treeObject));
```